# Booklet with pdfpages: avoid rotation

Tags: pdfpages

I'm trying to print an A5 booklet on A4 paper.

With

```
\includepdf[pages=-,landscape,noautoscale,booklet]{myfile}
```

(or `signature=20` instead of `booklet`), where `myfile` is the original A5 pdf, the pages are set correctly, but the sheet are "twisted":

[image]

but

[image]

Is it possible to have all the sheets in the same direction? It could be easier to print...

Comment: well "booklets" are typically folded and some sheet must turn. If you don't want that don't use the booklet option and arrange the page with the other pdfpages options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. In fact, if you print on A4 and fold in the middle you don't need that rotation. But it's true that one can rotate the physical sheets while feeding them to the printer :-)

Comment: In the printer seetings menu where you enable double-sided printing you will find a switch to toggle between long and short edge flipping of the page.